# How to read / write file with org.apache.cordova.file

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using `ionic` framework and I would like to read / write a file with the `org.apache.cordova.file` plugin.

How can I do it? (I haven't found any working examples for doing it)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following thread can help you [How do you store a file locally using Apache Cordova 3.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22336597). In this post you can read about file management with apache cordova.

But you could  check:
- grammar spelling, always there are some typos.
- check the path of the the files are right defined.